# Where does phpmyadmin action logs are stored?

Tags: phpmyadmin

Sorry if this was already asked, I could find it.

Where can I see what phpmyadmin did exactly in terms of sql operation when I do anything in phpmyadmin UI?

For example: If I create database using phpmyadmin, I want to see what SQL operations/commands were executed by phpmyadmin to create the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For many operations, there is a "Preview SQL" button next to the Go or Save button, such as on the table Structure tab:

[image: Preview SQL button]

You can see some history through the Console tab:

[image: Console interface]

Finally, there's a feature for change tracking, which isn't specifically designed to be used in this way, but would show a lot of the SQL commands used.

Aside from those, I don't think there is much you can do aside from directly viewing the MySQL binary log — which certainly is an option, but isn't specifically a phpMyAdmin feature.